# How to upload an Excel file into ContentVersion Object

Tags: opportunity, contentversion, contentdocument

I need to upload an Excel file on an opportunity. I want to user ContentVersion standard object to store these excel files.

> Can anyone please explain or share a code snippet to show how can we
>   upload an excel to an ContentVersion object and how to associate the
>   uploaded record with an opportunity?
>
> can you please also explain difference between ContentVersion and
>   ContentDocument objects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [Content Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content) Data Model for the relationship between ContentVersion and ContentDocument.

[image: Content Objects Schema]

One ContentDocument can have one or more ContentVersion records. The ContentVersion contains the actual data.

Use the [ContentVersion](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) to create the new record. The Excel file data should be stored in the `VersionData` field. You will also want to set the `Title` and `PathOnClient` (including the file extension) fields.

The [ContentDocumentLink](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) can be used to create the link to a record that supports chatter feed tracking (including custom objects).

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am struggling uploading file in contentVersion using lightning component. Can you please guide me with this. Refer to below link for details :  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157024/uploading-file-in-contentversion-using-lightning-component